# Struggling with my Sony bluetooth headset dr-btn200 Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, bluetooth, headset

I have contacted Sony about it, but they simply say that they do not support windows os as this bt headphone is made for phones. (even though [windows is listed here](http://www.sony.nl/support/nl/product/DR-BTN200#Compatibility))

I have checked [this](http://helpguide.sony.net/mdr/dr-btn200/v1/nl/contents/01/02/02/02.html) and [this](http://helpguide.sony.net/mdr/dr-btn200/v1/nl/contents/06/02/03/03.html) ([english](http://helpguide.sony.net/mdr/dr-btn200/v1/gb/index.html)) and I want an a2dp connection. Sorry for linking to dutch files (I cannot switch it to en-us) here is a PDF in English: http://pdf.crse.com/manuals/4446293521.pdf

Translation for the dutch url:

> If you have paired this devices, you can press the play button to get a a2dp connection if the headphone is turned on.

The PDF says I have to press the power button for 2 seconds to turn it on and after that press play to start an a2dp connection. It seems that Windows only uses the hands-free mode which has low audio quality.
The first screenshot is the current situation and the second one the desired situation.

[image: current situation]
[image: desired situation]

ps. the hardware is a surface pro3 with build-in bt support
pps. there is a suggestion to disable the recording/mic of the headphone, but does not seem to work either https://superuser.com/a/189443/24642

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since you posted that, so you probably solved this issue. For an unknown reason, the microphone doesn't work well on Windows. When you connect the "headset" to your Windows, it struggles with the sound.

What I do to solve this is to disconnect the headset and connect only the headphones and this makes the sound clear again.

Comment: I have windows 10 now and it works much better. I keep the `power` button pressed for about 3 seconds and after that the `play/pause` button for 2 seconds and then release it and press and hold it again for 3 or 4 seconds. I do not know if this is the right procedure, but it connects every time now in Windows 10. Works now, so I am happy.